# Calculating gaps between time in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

In my PostgreSQL database I have the following schema:

```
CREATE TABLE programs (
    id integer,
    description text
);

CREATE TABLE public.messages (
    id integer,
    program_id integer,
    text text,
    created_at timestamp with time zone
);

INSERT INTO programs VALUES(1, 'Test program');

INSERT INTO messages VALUES(1,1, 'Test message 1', now() - interval '7 days');
INSERT INTO messages VALUES(2,1, 'Test message 2', now() - interval '4 days');
INSERT INTO messages VALUES(3,1, 'Test message 3', now() - interval '1 days');
```

I want to calculate gaps between `created_at` in messages table. It should work this way:

1. Calculate gap between `created_at` of first and second message.
2. Calculate gap between `created_at` of second and third message.
3. Calculate average gap based on those values.

Is there any way of doing such a thing in PostgreSQL?

https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gvxijmp8u6wr6mYcSoAeVV/0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `LAG` and windowed `AVG` to get both difference and average gap:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT *, 
  created_at-LAG(created_at) OVER(PARTITION BY program_id ORDER BY created_at) gap
  FROM messages
)
SELECT *, AVG(gap) OVER(PARTITION BY program_id) AS avg_gap
FROM cte;
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_11&fiddle=244435b41b3a93ef1a0c77a17ee32bbe)**

Answer (score 1):

If you want the average time between messages, there is no need to get the successive differences.  Simply do look at the oldest and newest messages:

```
select program_id,
       (max(created_at) - min(created_at)) / nullif(count(*) - 1, 0)
from messages
group by program_id;
```